# Kernel of linear combination of functionals

Tags: linear-algebra

Given linear functionals $\varphi_2 = ( 2 , -2\alpha, 1)$ and $\varphi_1 = (2,1 -\alpha, -1)$ how do I find kernel of $\varphi_1 - 2\varphi_2$? ($\alpha$ is some parameter)

Is it so simple as $ker(\varphi_1-2\varphi_2)$? (Of course the kernel will be dependent on parameter $\alpha$)

Comment: How about simply computing $\phi_1-2\phi_2$ and then computing its kernel?

Comment: I don't understand the second question. Please clarify.

Comment: The second question is exactly what you've said in the first comment - computing the combination and then it's kernel. I'm asking if this is legit.

Comment: @NumberFour: Yes. You're asked to find the kernel of $\phi_1 - 2\phi_2$, which is $\ker(\phi_1 - 2\phi_2)$. Where's the confusion?

Comment: As you want to find the kernel of $\phi_1-2\phi_2$, yes, you should simply find $\ker(\phi_1-2\phi_2)$. As this is really a reformulation, Rasmus was confused how you could be confused about the first formulation when you seem to have no problem with the second ...

Comment: Ok thanks I just wanted to be sure!

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question...

Comment: @Rasmus: What is "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly board or rhetorical" about this question?

Comment: @CliveNewstead: I can't tell what's being asked in the "question". That's why I consider it as not a real question. I think my claim is supported by the fact that the accepted answer is merely a tautology without any actual content (no offense intended to Alan Simonin).

Comment: @Rasmus I think that the point not understood in the question is exactly the definition of the kernel, so yes I was tautological, but for learning purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \in ker (\phi_1 - 2 \phi_2) \iff (\phi_1 - 2 \phi_2) (x) = 0$.

And $(\phi_1 - 2 \phi_2)(x) = (-2x_1,(3\alpha +1)x_2,-3x_3)=(0,0,0)$, so you can solve the rest.